# Cannot launch any app on android created by Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, launch

It's impossible to launch any application in my Samsung Galaxy Ace (273 RAM) version 2.3.5 ( newest updated). I use Visual Studio 2015 (free version), I have x64 system, I added version 2.3 API 10 lvl.

1. New project
2. Blank App (Android), I put name: "ForStackOverflow"
3. Create

code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ForStackOverflow
{
[Activity(Label = "ForStackOverflow", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
}
}
}
```

I have USB connection, then I put two modes:
**a) Debug**

In Output I get:

*The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).
Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.*

1. Target is phone so I guess It's ok
2. ( MainLauncher = true), it's in code below namespace ForStackOverflow{...
3. Configuration Manager is ok, there is for both Release and Debug enable Deploy

**b) Release**
Output:
Deploy successfully on Samsung GT-S5830
Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped 
Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped

But it also appears error on phone:
Sorry!
Application ForStackOverflow (process ForStackOverflow.ForStackOverflow) has been unexpectedly stopped. Try Again. [below button: Force Stop]
// sorry if I did some mistakes with translation it.

AndroidManifest.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   package="ForStackOverflow.ForStackOverflow" android:versionCode="1"           android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<application android:label="ForStackOverflow"></application>
</manifest>
```

Screen: Android Device Logging
http://images77.fotosik.pl/852/4798b335f14877a4.png

I hope I gave all details concerning it. Just it's default app and It doesnt work. I wonder if change Visual to Android Studio or what ever to create any apps, I like C# so I have still hope for solution. In contrast, my emulator works well - App works in PC. So where is problem with Android and my phone?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance for all replies

Comment: Try Clean and Rebuild

Comment: Hmm not working, I guess mayby some configuration is incorrect

Comment: Its not much help I know, but this Visual Studio/Xamarin/Android midden is such a pile of dreadful stinking excrement ...